# Merge hash keys

Tags: ruby, hashmap

My hash is:

```
hash = { text:'abc', text1:'123', other values }
```

I want to have:

`{ text: 'abc123', other values }`

How can I merge two keys into single one (only `text+text1` should be merged)?

Comment: Are this the only values in that hash or is this just an example? Might there other keys too (let's say: `foo` and `foo1` and perhaps also `foo2`)?

Comment: ye,it's just example,there are other value

Comment: What is the pattern behind the keys? Is it always a combination of characters (like `foobar`) and the other keys start with the same combination, but end with a number (like `foobar9346`)? How should the values be ordered when joined?

Comment: only 1 and 2 key should be merged

Comment: You can improve your question by replacing "other values" with some key-value pairs: `hash = { text:'abc', text1:'123', cat:1, dog:2 }`. That way, `hash` becomes a Ruby object, so readers can give answers that return `{ text:'abc123', cat:1, dog:2 }`. Also, you need to specify which key's value is to be modified and which key is to be deleted. One way of doing that is to say that you want a method `my_method` such that `my_method(hash, merge_key, delete_key)` returns a hash that is the same as `hash` except....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `Object#tap` for your goal:

```
hash.tap { |h| h[:text] += h.delete(:text1) }
=> {:text=>"abc123", other_values}
```

Comment: Since `delete` returns the deleted value you might just want to use `h[:text] = h[:text] + h.delete(:text1)` and remove the following line.

Comment: Why do you need to tap an array instead of just modifying a string value inplace?

Comment: @mudasobwa, cause author want to return a hash

Comment: If I parsed English properly, OP wants _to have_ a hash :)

Comment: Worth mentioning that `hash` is mutated. OP has not specified whether the hash is to be mutated or a new hash is to be returned.

Answer (score 6):

```
hash[:text] << hash.delete(:text1)
```

Comment: nit and clean solution

Comment: @Gagan, I'm not sure about "nit", but it's certainly clean. Mudsie, good one! `h = hash.dup; h[:text] << h.delete(:text1)` if `hash` is not to be mutated.

Comment: @CarySwoveland if hash is not to be mutated, the solution with `hash.dup.tap` seems to fit better: it will return the hash itself and it does not require the temporary local variable.

Comment: `tap` does not use a temporary variable (albeit one that is better confined)?

Comment: @CarySwoveland temporary _local_ variable.